# how do i split numbers in a array ? javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im trying to split all the numbers in a array:

```
var array_code = [116,101,120,116];
```

So i want the result to look like this: [1,1,6,1,0,1,1,2,0,1,1,6]

the code im working on right now looks like this:

```
var array_gesplit = new Array; 

for(var i=0; i< array_code.length; i++){
    console.log(array_code[i])
    while (array_code[i]) { 
        array_gesplit.push(array_code[i] % 10 );
        array_code[i] = Math.floor(array_code[i]/10);

    }
}
```

The result im getting from this is: 
[
  6, 1, 1, 1,
  0, 1, 0, 2,
  1, 6, 1, 1
]

Who can help me ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method for this:

```js
var array_code = [116,101,120,116];
var result = Array.from(array_code.join(''), Number)
console.log(result)
```

Explanation:

- `array_code.join('')` creates a string like `"116101120116"`
- `Array.from('116101120116')` on this string results in new Array of strings like:

  - `["1", "1", "6", "1", "0", "1", "1", "2", "0", "1", "1", "6"]`
- We can also use `Array.from()` with map function, so that we can convert all these string values to Number in one line like:

  - `Array.from(array_code.join(''), x => Number(x))`
  - Or, just `Array.from(array_code.join(''), Number)`
  - The above logic result is the required output.

Comment: Just as a side-note `x => Number(x)` is reducible to simply `Number`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `flatMap()` and convert number to string and use built-in `split()` method.

```js
var array_code = [116,101,120,116]; 
const res = array_code.flatMap(x => x.toString().split('').map(Number));
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take strings and map numbers.

```js
var code = [116, 101, 120, 116],
    result = code.flatMap(v => Array.from(v.toString(), Number));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hack by using some details of the JavaScript language:

```js
var array_code = [116, 101, 120, 116];
var array_string = JSON.stringify(array_code);
var array_parts = [].slice.call(array_string);
var parts = array_parts.slice(1, -1);  // get rid of the square brackets
console.log(parts);
```

Comment: That's not an array of numbers, it's an array of numeric strings and also `","`